# What is CAN Active, CAN passive and Sleep state in CAN Network manager?

Tags: embedded, can-bus, automotive

I am trying to understand the CAN network management in vehicle. During my research, I got to know that CAN network management(CANNM) will make some Mode state to decide the CAN transmission. Those modes are CAN active, CAN passive and CAN sleep states. I want to know that is the exact use of CANNM and why these modes are required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommended to read [Autosar Network Management Spec](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/foundation/19-11/AUTOSAR_PRS_NetworkManagementProtocol.pdf)

Where you will got the idea behind that.
Maybe in your term it differences but likely same
CAN Active : If at least one NM node in a NM cluster needs
communication, the NM protocol ensures that all required
NM nodes remain awake.

Can Sleep : If there is no communication need in a NM cluster, the
NM protocol ensures that all NM nodes synchronously
enter sleep mode

Can Passive : NM node configured as Passive node is not able to
initiate a start-up of a NM cluster, however is able to be
woken up if any other node initiates a start-up. This
eliminates unnecessary communication and reduces bus
and buffer overhead. Allowing shutdown to be controlled
by a subset of the cluster’s nodes enables the possibility
that only fault tolerant nodes control shutdown.

Long said short what all this for a Startup/Wakeup and Sleep/Shutdown for ECUs in network